# Checking the balance factor of each node in a BST and storing it in the node

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write this function that will store the Balance of each node in a BST and store it inside the node. In my BST I have added variable bal to store it.

I am still a beginner when it comes to recursion so excuse any errors i just need help to see if my logic is correct or if there is a better way!
Here is my function:

```
 void calculateBalanceValue(BinaryNode *& t)
        {
            if (t==nullptr) return;

            int left = height(t->left);
            int right = height(t->right);
            t->bal=abs(left -right);
            calculateBalanceValue(t->right);
            calculateBalanceValue(t->left);

        }
```

Comment: It seems correct to me. Is `height` also a recursive function call? Because then, while it is correct, you are doing the same work very often. Consider one child of your root. You calculate the height for this child when you call the function for the root, and with this you also call `height` for the grandchildren. Now when you calculate the balance value for the child, you again call `height` for the grandchildren. This is not really necessary, maybe you want to think about a different way to do this. Also, don't pass pointers by ref, pass the pointer by value or the `BinaryNode` by ref.

Comment: But the logic is correct right?

Comment: It seems so to me. This will certainly traverse all nodes and it will store this difference in the node. I of course cannot say if the `height` method is correct, but locally this method is correct. A good practice would be to write some tests for your Tree (different inputs checked versus the expected outcome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic looks reasonable to me, but it looks to me like it would be fairly trivial to make it roughly twice as fast.

Right now, you traverse each sub-tree once to compute its height, then you traverse at again to calculate its balance.

Since it needs to traverse the sub-trees to do its job anyway, I'd have `calculateBalance` return the height of the tree. That way it's fairly trivial to compute both the balance and the height with a single traversal.

Since we don't want to modify a pointer being passed to this function, I'd just pass the pointer by value.

```
int calculateBalanceValue(BinaryNode *t)
    {
        if (t==nullptr) 
            return 0;

        int left = calculateBalance(t->left);
        int right = calculateBalance(t->right);
        t->bal=abs(left -right);
        return 1 + std::max(left, right);
    }
```

As an aside, if you want critiques of working code, you might want to check on Stack Exchange's [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) web site, which is devoted to exactly that.